# how to integrate prettyPhoto with wicket

Tags: jquery, wicket

I'm trying to integrate a wicket ajax link's response with prettyPhoto. I'm having difficulty getting the wicket response to be displayed within the prettyPhoto lightbox.

Comment: Are you trying to use prettyPhoto to display wicket pages as iframes, like the second to last example on their main page?

Answer (score 0):

prettyPhoto API might help: [API Link](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#api)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the API but the problem i'm having is that with the $.prettyPhoto.open() function seems to work only with images.. plus with a wicket AjaxLink the url's are auto generated and the click action actually occurs as a function (part of their security i guess) and so it's really difficult for me adding prettyPhoto the normal way (i.e. using the prettyPhoto.init())